# Reading multiple json file from S3 using Amazon Athena

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am storing the daily activities of employee on a folder as employee.json here is my structure of data stored in S3. Now I want to read the activities of all employees for a date range. How can I do that using Amazon Athena service? Or should I write a customer code to do that.

```
empId1-->2020-03-01-->employee.json
         2020-03-02-->employee.json
         2020-03-03-->employee.json
         2020-03-04-->employee.json
         2020-03-05-->employee.json

empId2-->2020-03-01-->employee.json
         2020-03-02-->employee.json
         2020-03-03-->employee.json
         2020-03-04-->employee.json
         2020-03-05-->employee.json

empId3-->2020-03-01-->employee.json
         2020-03-02-->employee.json
         2020-03-03-->employee.json
         2020-03-04-->employee.json
         2020-03-05-->employee.json

empId4-->2020-03-01-->employee.json
         2020-03-02-->employee.json
         2020-03-03-->employee.json
         2020-03-04-->employee.json
         2020-03-05-->employee.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at partitions in Athena: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html.

This will allow you run a query against a subset of of S3 files base don a prefix.